# How to change webpack config without Eject to set CSS as Module

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Is there any way to keep generic webpack.config.dev.js without ***eject***  but override some features in it?

So i need a way to add some lines to get css modules

```
import styles from './styles.css';
...
<div className={styles.A}
```

I would like to avoid the command ***eject*** because i dont want to lose updates from react-team and like when project file structure is clear.

My webpack 4.19.1 generated by create-react-app

One more question: may be is there any third-party library helps to achieve such modular css files?

Comment: This should work. You don't need to eject to import css as a module in React. By default `create-react-app` supports css modules.

Comment: hi @dineshPandiyan, this works only if `import './styles.css'` and `<div className="A-style"`, but it doesnt if we want add it as a module `import styles from './styles.css'`

Comment: Ah, I see. You're better off with using `styled-components` library instead of native css modules. It's a lot easier to work with and maintain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works by default in CRA 2.0+, though you should rename your css file to be styles.module.css

More info [here](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet)